# Linux: buddy system free memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, kernel

Could anyone explain this code?

```
page_idx = page_to_pfn(page) & ((1 << MAX_ORDER) - 1);
```

page_to_pfn() have already return the page_idx, so what does '&' use for? Or page_to_pfn() return something else?

Answer (score 3):

You need to know that `x & ((1 << n) - 1)` is a trick meaning `x % ((int) pow(2, n))`. Often it's faster (but it's better to leave these kind of optimizations to the compiler).

So in this case what this does it does a modulo by `pow(2, MAX_ORDER)`. This causes a wrap-around; if page_idx is larger than `pow(2, MAX_ORDER)` it will go back to 0. Here is equivalent, but more readable code:

```
const int MAX_ORDER_N = (int) pow(2, MAX_ORDER);

page_idx = page_to_pfn(page);

/* wraparound */
while (page_idx > MAX_ORDER_N) {
    page_idx -= MAX_ORDER_N;
}
```

Comment: But why the buddy system need a wrap-around? What's more, how could this code return the correct page frame number? I mean page_to_pfn() have return the correct one, and the follow wrap-around will turn it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit mask that ensures that page_idx does not exceed a certain value (2^MAX_ORDER).

```
# define MAX_ORDER (8)

(1 << MAX_ORDER) /* 100000000 */
- 1 /* flip bits, same as ~(…) due to two-complement: 11111111 */
```

So you only have the eight least significant bits left

```
  1010010101001
& 0000011111111
= 0000010101001
```

Comment: But why page_idx could not exceed 2^MAX_ORDER? What does it mean to buddy system?

Comment: It cannot exceed 2^MAX_ORDER because the bit mask is applied and clears all bits greater than that.

Comment: I mean why buddy system have to limit page_idx in 2^MAX_ORDER.

Comment: Because it limits the number of pages to 2^MAX_ORDER? In other words: the maximum number of pages is defined as 2^MAX_ORDER.

Answer (score 0):

chekck this function will be clear:

```
static inline struct page * 
__page_find_buddy(struct page *page, unsigned long page_idx, unsigned int order)
    {
            unsigned long buddy_idx = page_idx ^ (1 << order);
    
            return page + (buddy_idx - page_idx);
    }
```

it just limits page_idx into a range of 8MB, maybe because the maximum block size is 4MB (1024 pages), it can not be merged again, only 2MB blocks can merge into 4MB, and the buddy block can be before or after the page, so
the whole range is [page_idx - 2MB, page_idx + 2MB] ??

its absolute size is not important, but offset (buddy_idx - page_idx) is important, add page to get the real buddy address.